# CodeIgniter Project Starter

Tags: php, ruby, codeigniter

I am wondering if there are any tools that you guys use to kick-start a CodeIgniter project similar to ROR? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Codeigniter is really not that kind of framework. While amazing, it's more of a library with some nice MVC stuff in it.

Answer (score 3):

I've only tried CodeCrafter (https://launchpad.net/codecrafter) and it's quite decent, but there are others:

```
http://*.com/trac/catalystmodel (see comment)
http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Rapyd_Components/
http://*.com/trac/quickmodel (see comment)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Do not go to ciforge.com! The domain is compromised, nothing but popups and redirects. Whatever was there when this comment was made was long gone.

Answer (score 3):

## Examine other code

Something that helped me enormously was going through the code base of the Redux 2 Authentication system (currently in beta).

The code for the project is well formatted and clear. It uses a model, view, controller, library and a decent config file for customisations.

The way the code is written will give you an insight into how a CodeIgniter project can be built in a very clean manner.

## Use a library

Other ways to get started quickly include using a library to grab data from an API. For example, try out the [Flickr](http://www.haughin.com/code/flickr/), [Twitter](http://www.haughin.com/code/flickr/) or [Last FM](http://www.haughin.com/code/lastfm/) libraries written by Eliot Haughin.

These enable you to use other site's data in interesting ways.

## Sample Application

There is also a sample application provided by Derek Allard at [this URL](http://video.derekallard.com/).

Comment: You've got to be kidding about Redux Auth 2, I had to debug the thing myself just to get basic functionality on some functions, and I don't buy the library-just-a-wrapper-for-module thing, I think it should contain everything inside redux_auth.php, sans the view files of course. But if you just look at it as an example app and not as a library per se, then you may have a good point.

Answer (score 1):

[This Net-tuts series](http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/) sold me on CI. It's not an actual kick-starter, but will guide you through the basics and some more in-depth stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how ROR does it, but if you have unpacked CI in a directory you can pretty much start creating your site. They also have some video tutorials if you need some help in how to start creating your site.
http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

Tools to kick-start a CodeIgniter project, hmm?  Debian, Apache, PHP 5, SciTE ... =)

Start by reading the [User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/).  It's some of the best documentation I've come across.

Then, if you've got a project in mind, figure out the feature set that project requires and start looking for CodeIgniter freebies on [the wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/).  There's a handful of helpers, libraries, plugins and such that will do a lot of the work for you.

Final side note: try to have an open mind.  If you're trying to "do Rails" in CodeIgniter, you're approaching things backwards.  Instead, try learning what makes CodeIgniter a great framework, and use those features as best you can.

Answer (score 0):

CI has a feature called Scaffolding, it's an admin-only GUI to your database through which you can quickly enter test data to start querying and displaying on your page.

The video tutorials and documentation and top-notch and it's really pretty easy to get a simple blog up and running.